# Javascript image preview for single image and multiple images for upload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to implement an image preview for both a main image and for multiple images in the same form. The below js works independently but when the functions are combined I can only get the main image preview to work but not the preview for the multiple images upload.  I'm not a js person by any stretch of the imagination but I believe the problem lies in the addEventListener which I have been unable to resolve.  Another thought was in the variables but I've tweaked them without success as well.  Any help would be greatly appreciated since I have not found a similar question any where on the web.

Here's a snapshot of the html/erb

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">
    Upload feature image <%= f.file_field :feature_image, style: 'display:none', onchange: "previewFeatureFile()" %>
  </label><br />
  <img id="feature_prev" src="#" height="200" />
</div> 

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">
    Upload multiple images <%= f.file_field :images, style: 'display:none', onchange: "previewImagesFiles()", multiple: true %>
  </label>
  <div id="preview"></div>
</div>
```

JS File

```
function previewFeatureFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('#feature_prev');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}

function previewImagesFiles() {

  var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
  var files   = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;

  function readAndPreview(file) {

    // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
    if ( /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name) ) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var image = new Image();
        image.height = 100;
        image.title = file.name;
        image.src = this.result;
        preview.appendChild( image );
      }, false);

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

  }

  if (files) {
    [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview);
  }

}
```

I'm using Rails 5.